# GET from JavaScript, problems parsing XML? Or Maps API errors?

Tags: javascript, xml, google-maps

I'm trying to make an HTTP get from Javascript, calling Google Maps to get transit duration from A to B, and then parsing the resulting XML as follows:

```
function getTransitTime(match) {
    var homeBase = '<Address 1>';
    var distURL = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&key=API_KEY_I_GOT&mode=transit&arrival_time=1519977600&origins=' + homeBase + '&destinations=' + match;

    parser = new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(httpGet( distURL ), "text/xml");
    var finRet = $(xmlDoc).find('duration').text()
    return finRet;
}

function httpGet(theUrl)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, true );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```

I receive both the NoApiKeys and SensorNotRequired errors in the js console. What am I doing wrong?

There are probably even more problems with this:

- I'm not sure how to deal with spaces in address 1 (and even worse, "match").
- Duration has two sub-fields (one being text), not sure if parsing is correct. Note that my query works correctly in the browser (with the same API key) and the output XML is pasted below:

```html
<DistanceMatrixResponse>
    <status>OK</status>
    <origin_address>New York, NY, USA</origin_address>
    <destination_address>Philadelphia, PA, USA</destination_address>
    <row>
        <element>
            <status>OK</status>
            <duration>
                <value>5100</value>
                <text>1 hour 25 mins</text>
            </duration>
            <distance>
                <value>145447</value>
                <text>145 km</text>
            </distance>
        </element>
    </row>
</DistanceMatrixResponse>
```

Any help? I wandered off trying to make something "simple" work, but ended up in the deep end :|

Comment: XMLHttpRequest is **asynchronous**

Comment: as far as the NoApiKeys error and the SensorNotRequired warning - please show the script tag where you load the google maps api

Comment: I get a CORS error with your code `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin is therefore not allowed access.`  Is there a reason you aren't using the `DistanceMatrix` service in the Google Maps Javascript API v3?

Comment: I'm doing this from within a Chrome extension, so no HTML around. I couldn't figure our how to load the maps API into that (even though I know how to do it for HTML.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix this:

First, get permissions to make cross-origin requests to the maps API, by including the following in the extension's manifest.json:

```
"permissions": ["https://maps.googleapis.com/"]
```

Next, change:

```
var finRet = $(xmlDoc).find('duration').text()
```

to

```
var finRet = $(xmlDoc).find('duration').find('text').text()
```

This works because the returned XML has a text tag nested inside the duration tag.

Lastly, the spaces in the URL for the maps call don't really make any difference. Thanks for everyone for reading and contributing. I'm still looking for a cleaner solution if there's one.